# unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to unicode

Tags: windows, python-2.7, unicode, flask, pip

I need to use `Flask` for a school project:

I have installed `Python 2.7.10` and `pip`

When trying to install Flask using: `pip install flask`, I get the following error:

```
unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to unicode
```

Any ideas about what the problem might be?

I'm on Windows by the way.

Thank you